# Start ProFTPD on Debian Wheezy boot

Tags: debian, startup, boot, proftpd

I've installed ProFTPD on Debian Wheezy and everything works fine, except it won't start up on boot.

I've tried the following after a lot of Googling:

```
update-rc.d proftpd defaults
insserv proftpd
ln -s /etc/init.d/proftpd /etc/rc5.d/
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Just type these commands :

`update-rc.d proftpd remove`

`update-rc.d proftpd defaults`

It worked for me !

Comment: it's always better to explain why did it work (especially when one of the commands involves removal of something)

Answer (score -1):

In some setups you have to set `RUN=yes` in `/etc/default/proftpd` manually in order run this service at boot.